# Combining the Same Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datatable

I want to combine the same columns. Here is an example:

```
    Name    X    Name    Y    Name       Z
0   Jack    5    Maria   8    John       12
1   Celine  14   Andrew  14   Jonathan   21
```

In the above example, I want to combine "***Name***" columns. It will be like this:

```
    Name    X    Y    Z
0   Jack    5    -    -
1   Celine  14   -    -
2   Maria   -    8    -
3   Andrew  -   14    -
4   John    -    -   12
5   Jonathan -   -   21
```

Type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: It is a list of what?

Comment: How did you derive the source DataFrame, is it using ``pd.concat`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution probably, but does the job. Open to improvements.

```
>>> df
     Name   X    Name   Y      Name   Z
0    Jack   5   Maria   8      John  12
1  Celine  14  Andrew  14  Jonathan  21

>>> pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i:i+2] for i in range(0, df.shape[1], 2)])
       Name     X     Y     Z
0      Jack   5.0   NaN   NaN
1    Celine  14.0   NaN   NaN
0     Maria   NaN   8.0   NaN
1    Andrew   NaN  14.0   NaN
0      John   NaN   NaN  12.0
1  Jonathan   NaN   NaN  21.0
```